# Multiple strategies not have to pass a token in dev

Tags: nestjs

Here is a similar question [on the GitHub Nest repository](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1555)

but I have multiple strategies.

```
export class AdminStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'admin')
```

I would like to not have to pass a token in dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `AdminAuthGuard` guard that extends `AuthGuard('admin')`

```js
export class AdminAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('admin') {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    // add your custom authentication logic here.
    return super.canActivate(context);
  }

  handleRequest(err, user, info) {
    if (err || !user) {
      throw err || new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```